# Paring down a JSON object to send to client in Typescript, declaratively?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, dry

So I have what I consider to be a common dilemma. I have a database object, a regular JS object that came from a document database, and I want to then send that object to my client. But some of the fields are sensitive, and they mustn't be revealed to the client.

In the C# world, I would just use Declarative Reflective programming to attach attributes to my C# object, indicating which fields are safe for client consumption, something like this:

```
[SafeForClient]
string MyProperty { get; set; }  // send to client. 

string SecretData { get; set; }  // Do NOT send to client.
```

Then I'd use reflection to gather all of the `[SafeForClient]` properties, construct my JSON, and send it down the wire.

No such luck in the JavaScript world though. There's no declarative metaprogramming on this level.

I have my types defined in TypeScript like this:

```
export type RoomForClient = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    exits: {[index in Direction]?: Exit }
}

export type Room = RoomForClient & {
    hiddenFlags: ScriptData;
}
```

All of the room data that makes it to the client is just a subset of the total room data. At present, I have one property that shouldn't be included, which isn't so bad... I can easily just remove that one attribute from the object. But in the future, when more are added... I'm going to be required to add those property names in two places; once in the `Room` definition, and once in the method to actually pare it down.

How do I go about creating a "RoomForClient" object if I have a "Room" object, without manually specifying all of the fields I either should or should not copy over? All of this type information is erased at runtime, so I honestly can't think of a way of doing this without violating the DRY principle. Which I consider a code smell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using Property or Accessor [Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html).

That way you can mark your properties similarly to the following:

```
export type RoomForClient = {
    @SafeForClient
    id: number;
    ...
}
```

Note: This will require the reflect-metadata library.